# What is a co-pay card?

Tags: meaning

What is a co-pay card? It's out only used with respect to pharmaceutical matters? The Wikipedia says so, but I need your comments to find the answer.

Comment: This is more industry-specific jargon than a general question of English, but "co-pay" is an abbreviation of "co-payment", in which you're purchasing a product or service and paying part off the cost out-of-pocket, and a third party is paying the balance. You and the third party are paying together. You're "co-paying". In contemporary Western culture, the most common type of co-payment is for medical treatment (not just Rx, but dr and hospital visits as well, and in many cases dental services or vision/eyeglass costs). But I'm sure there are other industries where the concept is applied.

Comment: To add to @DanBron's answer: the co-pay card is a debit card linked to a special tax-advantaged account, that you can use for your co-payment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to relate primarily (solely ?) to U.S. Medical Insurance practices, and hence is not a question about 'English Language & Usage'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three important terms related to Insurance Payment in Healthcare Industry.I work in one of the major EHR software company and know the importance of these three terms in billing-

**1. Deductible**

A deductible is the amount you pay for health care services before your health insurance begins to pay.

**2. Coinsurance**

Coinsurance is your share of the costs of a health care service. It's usually figured as a percentage of the amount we allow to be charged for services. You start paying coinsurance after you've paid your plan's deductible.

**3. Copay**

A copay is a fixed amount you pay for a health care service, usually when you receive the service. The amount can vary by the type of service. You may also have a copay when you get a prescription filled.

**Co-pay card** is nothing but a medium to pay the copay amount.Co-pay card details of a patient are entered in the Pharmacy software which is coded to automatically process the copay amount out of the entire claim amount.

So while choosing a plan we need to consider these three parameters and then take the decision of buying one.